# Find a Value in a Container

Tags: c++, c++11, collections

I have created a simple function to determine if a container contains a value. It allows for certain conditions to be set as well: where to to start searching for value, which way to search, whether to find the first or the last occurrence of the value, and whether or not to include the starting point. I want its return value to be either the index of the matching element, or -1 if no matches were found.

```
template<class Container, class T>
int Vec_Find(const Container& c, int size, const T& val, int pivot_idx = 0, 
             bool find_first = true, bool ltr = true, bool include_pivot = true)
{
    if (find_first && ltr)
    {
        if (include_pivot) pivot_idx++;
        int i = std::distance(std::begin(c), 
                    std::find(std::begin(c) + pivot_idx, std::end(c), val));
        if (i != size) return i;
    }
    else if (find_first && !ltr)
    {
        if (!include_pivot) pivot_idx--;
        int i = std::distance(std::find(std::rbegin(c) + (size - pivot_idx - 1), 
                                        std::rend(c), val), std::rend(c) - 1);
        if (i != -1) return i;
    }
    else if (!find_first && ltr)
    {
        if (include_pivot && (c[pivot_idx] == val)) return pivot_idx;
        int i = std::distance(std::find(std::rbegin(c), 
                            std::rend(c) - (pivot_idx + 1), val), std::rend(c) - 1);
        if (i != pivot_idx) return i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (include_pivot) pivot_idx++;
        int i = std::distance(std::begin(c), 
                    std::find(std::begin(c), std::begin(c) + pivot_idx, val));
        if (i != pivot_idx) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I am a student to C++ and am looking for ways to code better, I appreciate all suggestions.

To Editors: I wasn't sure if I should leave my long lines on one line or fit to screen, please let me know if they should be on one line, and I will update it.

Comment: As I understand it from reading other posts you should leave the lines of code you post _exactly_ as you have them in your source. If they are too long, that _could_ be something to work on in your coding. As a beginning programmer you will develop your own coding habits and style. Posting for reviews here on CR, and paying attention to the comments, can help to make those _good_ habits early. The code you post here should work if it is copy & pasted directly into an editor, without having to reformat or adjust any lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Parameters

As a starting point, I'd usually advise against passing `bool`s as parameters--especially passing more than one `bool` to a particular function. I have better ways to spend my time than memorizing the meaning of:

```
foo(..., false, false, true);
```

vs.

```
foo(..., false, true, false);
```

I suppose I could barely see something like this if you were doing something like passing some `bool`s, and it was putting them together into a bit set, so `true, false, true` basically just meant `101`, but for something like this where each has a unique meaning, it seems unusually difficult to read.

#### Basic Utility

At least in my opinion, however, that nearly pales compared to the mere fact that I don't see much point in the function existing at all.

People who are accustomed to C++ are generally fairly accustomed to how the standard library works. Most of use would generally *rather* get an iterator than an index. If we want to search from end to beginning, passing `rbegin()` and `rend()` to `find` makes that intent fairly clear.

For example, if I want to search for the last item, starting 4 from the end, I'd have a much easier time understanding this:

```
auto p = std::find(foo.rbegin()+4, foo.rend(), value);
```

...rather than:

```
int p = Vec_find(foo, foo.size(), value, 4, false, true, true);
```

or:

```
int p = Vec_find(foo, foo.size(), value, 4, true, false, true);
```

[At least as I read things, those are basically the same--either find the last item, or find the first, starting from the end. Oh, and pardon me if I'd passed the wrong thing for the `size` parameter--I couldn't figure out exactly what it was supposed to do.]

Granted, iterators do tend to lead to fairly verbose code, but in this case, using your code can be even more verbose. I'm pretty sure when ranges become generally available (and sooner, for people who only need to target one compiler, or don't mind using Boost) quite a few people will welcome them with open arms. They can reduce verbosity quite a bit. Given a choice, however, between using this and using the standard library directly, I'd take the standard library without a second thought.